# How to clearly kill a mpi program which is launched by Qprocess?

Tags: qt, pyqt, mpi

I have a pyqt program and there is a requirement to run an external mpi program. I use Qprocess to launch the mpi program. Howerer, I find when I call kill method to terminate the mpi programs, the mpi processes is still running. Do anyone know how to clearly kill the mpi grograms launched by Qprocess?

Below is my test program:

**test.py**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread, QProcess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor

class worker(QThread):
    logChange = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        process = QProcess()
        command = f"mpiexec -n 8 test_mpi.exe"
        process.start(command)
        process.waitForStarted()
        self.stopFlag = False
        while True:
            if self.stopFlag:
                process.kill()
                process.waitForFinished(-1)
                self.logChange.emit("STOP!\n")
                break

            if process.waitForReadyRead(1000):
                output = process.readAllStandardOutput()
                output = bytearray(output).decode("gbk")
                self.logChange.emit(output)
            else:
                QApplication.processEvents()
                if process.state() == 0:
                    self.logChange.emit("FINISHED!\n")
                    break

    def stop(self):
        self.stopFlag = True

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.runButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.runButton.setObjectName("runButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.log = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.log.setObjectName("log")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.log)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.runButton.setText(_translate("Form", "run"))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("Form", "stop"))

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def logOutput(self, text):
        self.ui.log.insertPlainText(text)
        self.ui.log.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_runButton_clicked(self):
        self.logOutput("start running...\n")
        self.worker = worker()
        self.worker.logChange.connect(self.logOutput)
        self.worker.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_stopButton_clicked(self):
        if self.worker:
            self.worker.stop()
            self.logOutput("stop running...\n")
            self.worker = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test_mpi.cc**

```cpp
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  if (world_rank == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
      std::cout << "This output is from test mpi program: " << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

When I clicked the `stopButton`, mpi processes are still running showed in my task manager.
[image]

And I have learned I can kill it by using `taskkill /IM test_mpi.exe /F`, but this command will also terminate the test_mpi.exe started by other programs.  So my question is how to clearly kill a mpi program which is launched by Qprocess.

Comment: "when I call kill method to terminate the mpi programs"? How are you *actually* trying to kill that program? Because if that code is run in the main thread, you'll never get anything useful if you're trying to set that `self.stopOneFlag` by using UI elements. The event loop must be *always* left alone with its control as much as possible, and while loops obviously prevent that. Please provide a *valid* [mre], otherwise we won't be able to answer you, but ensure that you understand the concepts above and do some serious research on the matter before that.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply. This code snippet is in a QThread instance, and my main thread will modify stopOneFlag in this QThread object, so the QThread object will enter stop procedure when my main thread set stopOneFlag to True. I'm sure the codes in stop procedure is executed, but only qprocess itself will be killed not the mpi processes.

Comment: I have modified above code snippet to make problem more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, but your modification did not make it clearly. Please read the link in my previous comment more carefully. We need something we can *actually* work with, and right now your code is not a proper one (`start()` runs the process asynchronously, when you call `kill()` the process might not even be started yet). Take your time, rushing questions won't help you.

Comment: `mpiexec` will spawn 8 instances of `my_mpi_program` that are unknown to Qprocess. So your best bet is to first `SIGTERM` `mpiexec`, and hope `mpiexec` will terminate the MPI processes. you might want to double check after a few seconds `mpiexec` has been killed and `SIGKILL` it otherwise.

Comment: @musicamante I edited my problem again and provide minimal valid codes. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I run the code on windows, and there is no `SIGKILL` signal. And killing `mpiexec` don't affect spawned mpi processes. /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: what if you `process.terminate()` instead of `process.kill()` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet process.terminate() will wait for the mpi processes to completely finish. And I find this may be a bug of intel mpi on windows [https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-HPC-Toolkit/InteloneAPI-MPI-2021-2-0-behavior-on-Linux-and-Windows-differ/td-p/1290020]. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: `ps guwax | grep test_mpi.exe | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`. There you go.

Comment: that will also kill `test_mpi.exe` from other jobs/users